# Handling a PUT API call to write to a database using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, promise

The following function is accepting PUT connection to a server API, checks authorization to write and then performs write to a database.

The `eslint` linting tool complains saying "avoid nesting promises" and "Each then() should return a value or throw". I'm new to promises and I am not sure how to improve my code.

```
app.put('/api/v0/note/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const uid = req.user ? req.user.uid : null;
  return user_can_edit_note(uid, id).then(yes => {
    if (yes) {
        return db.collection('notes').doc(id).update({
          title: req.body.title,
          text: req.body.text,
          author_uid: req.user ? req.user.uid : null,
          updated_on: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
        }).then(() => {
          return res.json({
            ok: "ok"
          });
        });
    } else {
      return res.status(403).json({
        error: "Permission Denied",
        note_id: id
      });
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({error: String(err)});
  });
});
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Nothing fancy, we just wrapped the result in an array
const promise1 = someAsyncOperation()
const promise2 = promise1.then(result => [result])
promise2.then(result => console.log(result)) // [result]

// More concisely
someAsyncOperation()
  .then(result => [result])
  .then(resultInArary => console.log(resultInArray)) // [result]
```

Whatever you return in `then` becomes the resolved value of the promise it returns. In this case, when `promise1` resolved, we added a `then` that wrapped the result in an array. The returned value becomes the resolved value of `promise2`.

Now here's where everyone fails when talking about promises. They miss explaining this one behavior which is vital to the concept of "promise chaining":

```
const promise1 = asyncOperation1()
const promise2 = promise1.then(result1 => asyncOperation2())
promise2.then(result2 => {
  // This will not be invoked until asyncOperation2()'s promise resolves.
  // Also, result2 is NOT asyncOperation2()'s promise, but its resolved value.

  console.log(result2) // [result]
})

// More concisely
someAsyncOperation()
  .then(result1 => asyncOperation2())
  .then(result2 => {
    // This will not be invoked until asyncOperation2()'s promise resolves.
    // Also, result2 is NOT asyncOperation2()'s promise, but its resolved value.

    console.log(result2) // [result]
  })
```

When you return *a promise* in a `then`, two things happen that's different from returning a "normal value".

1. It uses the resolved value of `asyncOperation2()` as the resolved value of `promise2`, not the promise returned by the function call.
2. `promise2` will not resolve and its callbacks will not be invoked until the promise returned by `asyncOperation2()` resolves.

By now, you should now see how promise "chaining" is achieved. It's because of this one trick, returning promises in `then`, that allows subsequent `then`s to "wait" for (more precisely, not fire callbacks until) the previous promise. You could have code that looks like:

```
asyncOp1()
  .then(r1 => asyncOp2())
  .then(r2 => asyncOp3())
  .then(r3 => asyncOp4())
  .then(r4 => asyncOp5())
  .then(r5 => console.log('done'))
  .catch(e => console.log('one of the above failed'))
```

So in your code's case, it would look like this:

```
class ForbiddenError extends Error {
  constructor(message){
    super(message)
    // Add additional properties
  }
}

app.put('/api/v0/note/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  const uid = req.user ? req.user.uid : null

  user_can_edit_note(uid, id)
    .then(yes => {

      // The catch() down below will, uhm... catch this throw.
      if(!yes) throw new ForbiddenError()

      // Return the promise of this operation. The next then() handles it.
      return db.collection('notes').doc(id).update({
        title: req.body.title,
        text: req.body.text,
        author_uid: req.user ? req.user.uid : null,
        updated_on: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Update completed, respond with ok.

      return res.json({
        ok: "ok"
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // Any throws not recovered in the sequence will invoke this catch.
      // Use this to evaluate your error. You can extend Error to have it carry
      // custom properties and messages.

      if(err instanceof ForbiddenError){
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: "Permission Denied",
          note_id: id
        })
      } else {
        return res.status(500).json({
          error: "Server error"
        })
      }
    })
})
```